# PHP SQL convert time to compare and display

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a design of a page as the code below.
There are details passed from previous page to this page and at this page. 
this is the page for user to pick a date and check for availability. 
I'm stuck at the step to convert datetime to unixtime for comparison with database. And also after compare, isit possible to disable the slot button if its not available?

The requirement is to select time by hour, from 9-5, and store the selected datetime and the other information passed from previous page.

Thanks

```html
<?PHP
 session_start();
 
 $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
 $cname = $_POST['cname'];
 $cadd = $_POST['cadd'];
 $cphone = $_POST['cphone']
  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js"></script>
<title>Trial </title>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>
        Reservation Form
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
      <form method="post" action="datetime.php">
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="date">
            Select Date
          </label>
          <input type="datetime-local" step="3600" name="datetime" id="datetime" value=""/>  
 <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
   <label for="slot">
     Slot 
   </label>
        <input type="button" value="Slot 1" data-role="button" />
 <input type="button" value="Slot 2" data-role="button" />
 </div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Check Availability" data-role="button" data-inline="true"/>
</div>
<div>
<input type="submit" value="Next" data-role="button" data-inline="true"/>
</div>
</form>
    <div data-role="footer">
      Test
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I am little confused with your requirement, but check below solution, use the solution as per your requirement.

MYSQL DATE field format is 'YYYY-MM-DD', ex. '2017-11-14',
In your form user will insert the date, and the form submit, in the PHP script where the form submit, get the date value and convert in the same

```
$date = '14.11.2017'; // Get the date from POST
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
//echo $new_date;
```

Now check the $new_date in your database. Like "SELECT date_field FROM your_table WHERE date_field = '$new_date'"

Comment: i want to convert the datetime to unix time in the same page before storing to database. meaning that i will only compare based on the unix time. 
the requirement is for user to choose a date, and show if the 2 slots are available. if count 0 in database means both available, will be reflected on the button either enable or disable.

Comment: $date = '14.11.2017';
$datetime = new DateTime($date);
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();